# How to check if a string does not contain certain characters?

Tags: bash

I have bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ] || [ -z $3 ]
then
{ echo >&2 "Required parameters missing "; exit 1; }
fi

echo "Success"
```

The script needs 3 required parameters. But I also needs to make sure $1 does not contain . and $2 and $3 does not contain . and / and \

.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the `${name?:msg}` form of parameter expansion to verify you *have* non-empty values:

```
: ${1?:Missing parameter 1}
: ${2?:Missing parameter 2}
: ${3?:Missing parameter 3}
```

Then, use the `[[ ... ]]` command to perform pattern matching.

```
if [[ $1 = *.* ]]; then
  echo >&2 "Invalid parameter 1 "
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $2 = *[./\\]* ]]; then
  echo >&2 "Invalid parameter 2 "
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $3 = *[./\\]* ]]; then
  echo >&2 "Invalid parameter 3 "
  exit 1
fi
```

If you need to stick to POSIX constructs, use a `case` statement instead of `[[ ... ]]`:

```
case $1 in
  *.*) echo >&2 "Invalid parameter 1"; exit 1;;
esac

case $2 in
  *[./\\]*) echo >&2 "Invalid parameter 2"; exit 1;;
esac

case $3 in
  *[./\\]*) echo >&2 "Invalid parameter 3"; exit 1;;
esac
```

Comment: chepner thank u for detailed answer.  . and forward slash works fine but test for backslash fails. parameter containing backslash \ should return as invalid parameter. Both posix and [[ ]] has this problem

Comment: How are you testing the backslash case?

Comment: like enter ./test.sh param1 par\am2 param3, test passes but shud fail on second param

Comment: The shell is processing `par\am2` to `param2` before your function sees it. You need to escape the backslash, e.g., `./test.sh param1 "par\am2" param3`.